# PC won't post with 4 RAM sticks

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, ddr3

I have a few question if possible.

I have an old system which has the following components: CPU: i7 6700K, motherboard: Asus H110M2 D3, and a GTX 1060 3GB.

I wanted to upgrade the RAM to 32 GB (since it already had 16 GB). I had two old HyperX sticks and I thought of buying another set altogether, so I got 4 2-power 8 GB sticks at 1600 MHz 1.35 V (since they were really cheap, I think they sell in bulk or something).

The problem is that for some reason my PC won't post with all 4 sticks. I tried all the slots and sticks individually to see if anything is broken, it worked, then I tried 2x configurations in all 4 DIMM slots and it worked. But when I put all 4, the PC won't post.

Now, these 4 which I bought in bulk they say that they are single channel modules. Reading the [Asus manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/H110M2_D3/E10537_H110M2_D3_Guide_web.pdf?model=H110M2%20D3) it says this:

• 2 DIMM: Supports one pair of modules inserted into either the blue slots or the black slots as one pair of Dual-channel memory configuration
• 4 DIMM: Supports 4 modules inserted into both the blue and black slots as two pairs of Dual-channel memory configuration

Does the issue come from the RAM sticks not being dual channel? But if that would be the problem, why does it work with 2 pairs and not 4?

Should I return them and get two dual channel sets?

Comment: Possible clue from manual: "Due to Intel® chipset limitation, this motherboard can **only support single-side memories when four modules are installed** and they will run at the maximum transfer rate of DDR3 1066 MHz"

Comment: We would need a link to the DIMMs you are trying to use to be sure of their configuration. (The CPU has two memory "channels". It can use two channels at the same time to increase the memory access rate. Each channel can have up to two DIMMs, but it may not work as quickly as one DIMM per channel.)

Comment: It *should* work with two 16 GB DIMMs, if you want a total of 32 GB. You can check which RAM Asus has confirmed it works with at [H110M2 D3 RAM QVL](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/H110M2_D3/H110M2_D3_Memory_qvl.pdf?model=H110M2%20D3).

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. Seems like this should be the problem, the ram I bought is double sided.

Comment: @Yorik you should post that as an answer. It's a good answer.

Comment: I am not *totally sure* what single side memory even is, but if this turns out to be the problem, I don't object to the OP marking and accepting their own answer. I think it has to do with some sort of async access (single reads "all at once" and double sided alternates maybe)

Comment: @Yorik It's actually very simple: Single or double-sided just means it has chips on one side or both. And yes, for many boards/chipsets/CPUs combinations it makes a difference.